# MySQL "NOT IN" not working

Tags: mysql, notin

Strange thing happening.  I am having a problem with my MySQL Community Server 5.1 installed on windows ***NOT IN*** query.  When I do this query:

```
select * 
  from table1 
  where date >= "2012-01-01";
```

returns 582 rows

```
select * 
  from table1 
  where date >= "2012-01-01" 
    and the_key in (select some_key from table2);
```

returns 15 rows

so I would expect that the following query would return 582 - 15 = 567 rows

```
select * 
 from table1 
 where date >= "2012-01-01" 
 and the_key not in (select some_key from table2);
```

returns 0 rows

Why is this last query not returning any rows?

Comment: **key** is a keyword in SQL try quoting it with backticks

Comment: Try `where (date >= "2012-01-01") and (key not in ...)`; MySQL docs are vague on the `not in` operator and state that `expr NOT IN (value,...) is the same as NOT (expr IN (value,...))`, which might result in `NOT((date >= "2012-01-01" and key) IN (...))` in your case

Comment: yes some_key can be null, it is null some times

Comment: If the subquery returns null (in your case if some_key is null) then the "not in" clause does not work. Filter subquery such that some_key is not null

Comment: "not in" doesn't work . why? Is that a bug?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this.

```
select * 
 from table1 
 where date >= "2012-01-01" 
 and `key` not in (select some_key from table2 where some_key is not null);
```

Or using not exists

```
 select * 
 from table1 
 where date >= "2012-01-01" and not exists ( select some_key from table2 where table2.some_key = table1.key
```

Comment: Nice, they both work and seem to take about the same amount of time.  Thanks!

Comment: I would have up-voted this answer, but it only gives alternatives to the original approach.  It doesn't explain why the original approach doesn't work.  The answer from @Kibbee does explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 18):

Most likely you have some NULL values in your "key" column.  NULL comparisons always return null, which evaluates to false.  This can be counter intuitive. For example

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE SomeValue <> 0
```

Would not return the values with SomeValue = NULL.  Even though intuitively, NULL does not equal zero. So to fix the query you have, you should probably do the following.

```
select * from table1 where date >= "2012-01-01" 
and (key not in (select some_key from table2) OR key IS NULL);
```

Comment: In my case there also where null values in -> not in array query. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
 from table1 
 where date >= "2012-01-01" 
 and `key` not in (select some_key from table2);
```